# Does Google Pay support transferring funds to a PayPal account?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, payment, google-pay

I've succesfully implemented the client-side part of Google Play into my website.

However, I do not see PayPal in the list of supported processors, which feels a bit weird considering its popularity.

How do I make it so payments are received by a PayPal account, using the token I'm given?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because only google (or their docs) could answer that.

Comment: And I opened this question because their docs do not explain it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make it so payments are received by a PayPal account, using the token I'm given?

You use PayPal to accept the payments instead. Withdrawing money to PayPal is not what Google Pay is for, they are competitors.

Similarly, PayPal has no option to withdraw money to Google Pay.

You can withdraw from either service to a bank account.

(This is different from on the payer options side; there, you want to remove as much friction and entice the sale volume as much as possible.)

Answer (score 1):

Google Pay is a payment facilitator and does not process payments. Instead it securely shares payment details with partner payment processors. PayPal is not one of the supported payment processors.

This isn't directly related to your question but as an FYI, [Google Pay does partner with PayPal to help merchants accept PayPal payments](https://pay.google.com/about/paypal/)

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Pay users need to connect their PayPal account to Google Pay so they can pay with PayPal through their Google Pay Account.

https://pay.google.com/about/paypal

In other words PayPal is a source of money, like a bank account.